# Navigation bar gone since VS 11 install

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution that I still run in VS 2010. After opening the solution in VS2010 after install of Visual Studio 11 I noticed that  the navigation bar is missing.

The strange thing is that it is visible in some of the projects in the solution. This is indepedant of language. It seems like new projects always have a working navigation bar.

I tried to go into settings and uncheck and then go back and check navigation bar. Did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the window layout via the Window menu? Window -> Reset Window Layout

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> [Your Language] and make sure the  the "Navigation bar" checkbox is selected. [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/06/05/remove-the-navigation-bar-vstiptool0028.aspx)

Comment: It was. But the problem was resolved when I rebuilt the project.

Answer (score 5):

This was resolved by rebuilding the project and re-opening the code window for that class.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to upvote you.