# C# editor class view

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editor

Is there a way of making the C# editor in Visual studio 2010 behave like the visual basic editor where the left combo box lets you pick an object and the right one shows only its events/methods like VB?

I am working on a form with alot of controls and methods (Devexpress Ribbon Form) and all the controls, their methods, the forms methods are appearing in the right combo box and navigating to form methods is really cumbersome now,

or is there something built in within visual studio that I can use to navigate quickly between methods?

Comment: FYI, the language is named "C#", not "CSharp"

Comment: would appreciate your "fyi" more if you also said something connected with my question... FYI if you see Charp instead of C#, it means someone had problems with the "#" character either the keyboard, platform,etc woudnt allow it....

Comment: Or, alternatively, someone knew how the language name was pronounced, but not how it was spelled. I've seen that many times in the past three years.

Comment: i really dont think you can programme in C# and fail to write down the two characters...

Comment: It's a big planet, and we're not all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tools` -> `Options` -> `C#` -> `General`

Check the **Navigation bar** checkbox under the `Display` group

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have a problem similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131507/navigation-bar-gone-since-vs-11-install